# Spring Batch threads using partitioner

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm writing a spring batch application that need to use threads. I'm using partitioner.
All the logic, DAO's and entities are in an external jar.

Anyway, my question is... I'm splitting my application in 10 threads. When I look in the DB the table BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION, all my partitioners are there, but they are not been written at the same time. I don't know if it's right.

this is my batch config

```
@Bean
    public Job incomingJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("JOB_CONCEDER_PERFIL_NORMAL")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(partitionerStep()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step partitionerStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("PARTITIONER_STEP")
                .partitioner("slaveStep", partitioner())
                .step(stepConcederPerfilNormal()).gridSize(10)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepConcederPerfilNormal() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("STEP_CONCEDER_PERFIL").<PerfilProcessorVO, PerfilConcessaoNormalVO>chunk(500)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .faultTolerant()
                .skip(NonUniqueObjectException.class)
                .skipLimit(1000)
                .noRollback(NonUniqueObjectException.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PerfilPartitioner partitioner() {
        return new PerfilPartitioner();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public PerfilReader reader() {
        return new PerfilReader();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public PerfilProcessor processor() {
        return new PerfilProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public PerfilWriter writer() {
        return new PerfilWriter();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
        executor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(100);
        return executor;
    }
```

What I saw is that each threads just update the table just when the last one finish.

```
ID  VERSION STEP_NAME                                   JOB_EXECUTION_ID    START_TIME                  END_TIME            STATUS      COMMIT  READ    FILT    write
1   1       STEP_CONCEDER_PERFIL:PERFIL_PARTITIONER6    0                   16/01/20 14:29:51,137000000                     STARTED     0       0       0       0   
2   1       STEP_CONCEDER_PERFIL:PERFIL_PARTITIONER8    0                   16/01/20 14:29:51,138000000                     STARTED     0       0       0       0   
3   1       STEP_CONCEDER_PERFIL:PERFIL_PARTITIONER5    0                   16/01/20 14:29:51,136000000                     STARTED     0       0       0       0   
4   1       STEP_CONCEDER_PERFIL:PERFIL_PARTITIONER4    0                   16/01/20 14:29:51,135000000                     STARTED     0       0       0       0   
5   1       STEP_CONCEDER_PERFIL:PERFIL_PARTITIONER1    0                   16/01/20 14:29:51,138000000                     STARTED     0       0       0       0   
6   1       STEP_CONCEDER_PERFIL:PERFIL_PARTITIONER2    0                   16/01/20 14:29:51,136000000                     STARTED     0       0       0       0   
7   1       STEP_CONCEDER_PERFIL:PERFIL_PARTITIONER3    0                   16/01/20 14:29:51,136000000                     STARTED     0       0       0       0   
8   3       STEP_CONCEDER_PERFIL:PERFIL_PARTITIONER7    0                   16/01/20 14:29:51,139000000 16/01/20 14:34:33   COMPLETED   1       16      0       16  
9   1       STEP_CONCEDER_PERFIL:PERFIL_PARTITIONER9    0                   16/01/20 14:29:51,141000000                     STARTED     0       0       0       0   
10  15      STEP_CONCEDER_PERFIL:PERFIL_PARTITIONER0    0                   16/01/20 14:29:51,135000000                     STARTED     14      16      0       8   
0   1       PARTITIONER_STEP                            0                   16/01/20 14:29:43,813000000                     STARTED     0       0       0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Task Executor set concurrency limit

```
@Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
        executor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(100);
executor.setConcurrencyLimit(n)
        return executor;
    }
```